# Should I store a variable in a controller or in each view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, variables, visual-studio-2012, controller

I am developing a C# MVC 4 internet application in VS2012.

Whenever I create, edit, change details or delete an object from a list in a controller, I am removing the object from a list in another object.

My question is this: Should I just have an integer variable in the controller that has the id of the object where the list is located, or should I pass this integer variable to each ViewModel when creating, editing, changing details or deleting the object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass parameter to view for CRUD functions. because of duty of controller is act against of input parameters from every things such as other controllers, REST API, Web API and etc.